# AssertionError Minizinc for Python

Tags: minizinc

I got this error when trying out the sample code (https://minizinc-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) of the minizinc web.

```
from minizinc import Instance, Model, Solver

# Load n-Queens model from file
nqueens = Model("./nqueens.mzn")
# Find the MiniZinc solver configuration for Gecode
gecode = Solver.lookup("gecode")
# Create an Instance of the n-Queens model for Gecode
instance = Instance(gecode, nqueens)
# Assign 4 to n
instance["n"] = 4
result = instance.solve()
# Output the array q
print(result["q"])
```

The error I got was:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a64f1a5182f8> in <module>
      2 
      3 # Load n-Queens model from file
----> 4 nqueens = Model("./nqueens.mzn")
      5 # Find the MiniZinc solver configuration for Gecode
      6 gecode = Solver.lookup("gecode")

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\minizinc\model.py in __init__(self, files)
     85         self._lock = threading.Lock()
     86         if isinstance(files, Path) or isinstance(files, str):
---> 87             self.add_file(files)
     88         elif files is not None:
     89             for file in files:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\minizinc\model.py in add_file(self, file, parse_data)
    159         if not isinstance(file, Path):
    160             file = Path(file)
--> 161         assert file.exists()
    162         if not parse_data:
    163             with self._lock:

AssertionError:
```

I've downloaded both minizinc and python. I tried using jupyternotebook and spyder, but they both had the same issue.
If anyone has faced the same issue and fixed the problem I'll appreciate any feedback regarding this problem.

Comment: It seems like the problem is that `./nqueens.mzn` doesn't exist. Is that indeed the case?

Comment: I suppose, but i am not sure why it does not exist. I downloaded minizinc so that shouldn't be a problem. Could it be because of the directory or path?

Comment: You do have to create the file `./nqueens.mzn` on your own, it does not come with MiniZinc.

Comment: Oh got it, thank you. However, i am now faced with another error. ` RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`